# Sharing one physical image between two img elements in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is an image element , how do I use this same img element without sending another request to the server. Its important to note, I don't want image1.jpg downloaded twice from the webserver.  Any ideas?

```
    function loadCarousels(carouselLoc, carouselId) {

    $("li").find(carouselLoc).each(function (index) {
        var img = this;
        var outer = 0;

        $(carouselId).find("ul").each(function (innerIndex) {
            var liX = document.createElement("li");
            $(this).append(liX);
            var imgInner = document.createElement("img");
            imgInner.src = img.src;
            $(imgInner).appendTo(liX);
            console.log($(this));
        });
    });
}
```

Is how I currently try but it doesn't work. it creates a separate image.

Comment: Most browsers store pic in the catch so this should not be an issue

Comment: I'm seeing multiple requests to the webserver though

Comment: well not exactly what you might need, if you can use the image as background you can have a common css class...

Comment: Where are you seeing it requested? in the HTML?

Comment: In the network tab for Chrome. these are images based on url in a database. Its like a summary details view where we show the image in two places on the page

Comment: if user's cache is disabled not much you can do about it

Comment: Most likely the browser is receiving `304 Not Modified` status for the image, which means it's only downloaded once

Answer (score 1):

Browsers should be already pretty aggressive on caching images: Chrome often shows multiple requests, but if you check from the second on usually they're all satisfied using the cache.

In case you want to cache internally in your JS code, try to cache images by URL like the following:

```
// use this as JS cache
var images = {};

function loadCarousels(carouselLoc, carouselId) {

  $("li").find(carouselLoc).each(function (index) {
    var img = this;
    var outer = 0;

    // cache it
    if(!images[img.src]){
     images[img.src] = document.createElement("img");
     // if the user disable the cache, this should prevent another request
     images[img.src].src = img.src; 
    }

    $(carouselId).find("ul").each(function (innerIndex) {
        var liX = document.createElement("li");
        $(this).append(liX);
        // retrieve from the cache
        var imgInner = images[img.src];
        $(imgInner).appendTo(liX);
        console.log($(this));
    });
  });
}
```